# PowerBI Visualizations: Debug + Quick Compile

Tags: powerbi

I have been exploring the PowerBI visualizations github project and starting to make my own visualization but I'm having the following issues that is really slowing me down on the development:

- It takes almost 3m to run the "build", is there any other option for rapid development because when we are starting with the project 3m see the results of the code changed is too much...
- Is there any way to debug the visualizations inside the framework? I had setted the property "DEBUG" to false in the gulpfile.js but without success...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows user then just use Visual Studio 2015 solution PowerBIVisuals.sln from src/ folder
It has continuous build support, so that when you open the solution it will run continuous_build_debug task.

If you are a Unix/Linux/Mac user then you'll need to manually run continuous_build_debug. (Run "gulp continuous_build_debug")

This task will run Watchers which will build project parts after you save changes to any file.